# For Java's ScheduledExecutorService's scheduleAtFixedRate method does it return 1 ScheduledFuture or many?

Tags: java, concurrency

I ask this question because there is a command that executes multiple times. Does it return a ScheduledFuture every time the command executes or does it return a single ScheduledFuture at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a single `ScheduledFuture<?>` is returned upon scheduling the `Runnable command`.

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) returns

> **a** `ScheduledFuture` representing pending completion of the series
> of repeated tasks

You can also see this in the method signature:

```java
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate​(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

The `Runnable command` continues to be executed according to the configured interval without further intervention.

> The sequence of task executions **continues indefinitely until** one of
> the following exceptional completions occur:
>
> - The task is explicitly cancelled via the returned future.
> - The executor terminates, also resulting in task cancellation.
> - An execution of the task throws an exception.

Having a single `ScheduledFuture` returned by `scheduleAtFixedRate` provides a useful mechanism to programmatically discontinue all future scheduled executions of `Runnable command` through a call to [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) on the `Future`.

Comment: How can you complete an infinite series of tasks?

Comment: @swarbrick85 Look at the bulleted list that I quoted from the Javadoc.  You either cancel the `Future`, terminate the `Executor`, or the `Runnable` throws an `Exception`.

Comment: thanks I was trying to reconcile what I was reading here with what I was reading elsewhere. Elsewhere was talking about an endless series of Futures. I understand what you mean, and I understand what I was reading also.

Comment: @swarbrick85 If this answered your question, don't forget to accept it as the answer.